# Can you stop or increase the time interval for the Lazarus process of Prefect?

Tags: python-3.x, etl, prefect

Prefect has this [Lazarus process](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/concepts/services.html#lazarus) which is "responsible for rescheduling any submitted or running flow".

This issues is that if you have a retry delay over 10 min, your flow is killed by the Lazarus process.

Does anyone know if it’s possible to either disable or increase the time interval for the Lazarus process in order for such issues to not happen?

Comment: Lazarus never stops a Flow run or places it into a finished state, so your comment about retry delays flows being "killed" by Lazarus don't add up.  Lazarus only reschedules Flow Runs that have not entered a Running state from Submitted or that have tasks that have not yet completed.

Comment: Hm... okay so I will look into a reproducible example, so get to the bottom of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lazarus process can be stopped from the Prefect's UI > Select specific Flow > Settings.

The retry delay time is fixed at 10 min and currently it cannot be amended.